# How do i lock in dataGridView values without extra user input

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have this problem:

When user inputs data, and then immediately presses "Spausdinti" Button, last edited value in dataGridView doesn't save, because as far as I understand it's still being edited. "Spausdinti" button calls a function that immediately calculates data from dataGridView, and last edited Value doesn't count up, unless user presses Enter or another button. How do I overcome this situation?

[image]

Comment: Try to call `DataGridView.EndEdit` on `DataGridView.CellLeave` event or in `Button.Click`.

Comment: Oh Thanks, It works, I feel stupid or scrolling through the options and not noticing those.Thanks :)